# Cannot install open-coarrays-bin for gfortran on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, fortran

I have been trying to install [opencoarrays from here](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/open-coarrays-bin), using the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y open-coarrays-bin
```

It seems that every other Ubuntu version, this works fine. As mentioned in the question title, I am running Ubuntu 20.04, which seems to be an issue for this package, as it is not there. Running the above code gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package open-coarrays-bin
```

Does anyone know how to install OpenCoarrays on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal native method of installation is possible by using [different package names](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/open-coarrays):

```
sudo apt-get install libcaf-openmpi-3 libcaf-mpich-3
```

---

The mentioned `open-coarrays-bin` package is [available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/open-coarrays-bin) only for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, so you can download and install it manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hwloc/libhwloc5_1.11.9-1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openmpi/libopenmpi2_2.1.1-8_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/open-coarrays/libcaf-mpi2_2.0.0~rc1-2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/open-coarrays/open-coarrays-bin_2.0.0~rc1-2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/open-coarrays/libcoarrays-dev_2.0.0~rc1-2_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libhwloc5_1.11.9-1_amd64.deb ./libopenmpi2_2.1.1-8_amd64.deb ./libcaf-mpi2_2.0.0~rc1-2_amd64.deb ./open-coarrays-bin_2.0.0~rc1-2_amd64.deb ./libcoarrays-dev_2.0.0~rc1-2_amd64.deb
```

and then use it as it was planned.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Using your second suggestion, I do indeed now have coarrays installed, but when I try to compile code, for instance `caf test_coarray.f95 -o testcoarray`, I get the error:        `gfortran: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaf_mpi.a: No such file or directory
Error: comand:
   /usr/bin/mpifort -I/usr/include/OpenCoarrays-2.0.0-rc1_GNU-7.3.0 -fcoarray=lib test_coarray.f95 -o testcoarray /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaf_mpi.a
failed to compile.`

Comment: I have added the `libcoarrays-dev` package to get [a-library](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libcaf_mpi.a) installed.

Comment: mate, you are a legend. I have compiled coarray code that now runs. My only issue is a message that pops up at the start every run, `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1`. You wouldn't know what this is or how to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be caused by running the applications as *root* (or *sudo*'er). Try to launch your application as regular user.

Comment: Okay, Interesting, I am running the application as a regular user. specifically I run: `human@mind:~/Documents/code_testing_and_learning/test_fortran$ cafrun -np 6 testcoarray
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key hi, there, this is core:           2 from           6 cores
 hi, there, this is core:           3 from           6 cores
 hi, there, this is core:           4 from           6 cores
 hi, there, this is core:           5 from           6 cores
 hi, there, this is core:           6 from           6 cores
 hi, there, this is core:           1 from           6 cores`

Comment: Looks as warning, you can ignore it if it does not break compilation, then simply ignore it :)